# Apache startup failure - Centos7

Tags: apache, centos7

I ran a yum update after which HTTP Apache server fails to start up on my Centos 7 VM.

The apache details - `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16`

Kernel version - `3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`

Here is what the `systemctl` shows. I'm not able to figure out what is broken after the update.

```
[root@localhost log]# systemctl status httpd.service 
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-02-26 16:32:37 NZDT; 4min 19s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 3654 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/kdestroy -A (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3651 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3649 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3574 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/ipa/ipa-httpd-kdcproxy (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3649 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain ipa-httpd-kdcproxy[3574]: ipa         : WARNING  Disabling KDC proxy
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain httpd[3649]: [Fri Feb 26 16:32:37.213684 2016] [so:warn] [pid 3649] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain httpd[3649]: [Fri Feb 26 16:32:37.217181 2016] [so:warn] [pid 3649] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain httpd[3649]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directi... this message
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain kill[3651]: kill: cannot find process ""
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Could I please request help to get some pointers to dig further or anyone who has seen this before & knows how to fix please?

Comment: This `systemctl status httpd.service` doesn't provide much information. You can refer to apache log files or message logs. Also, this type of error comes due to library conflicts which apache is using. This might be the possibility that your current version of apache require different library version. And check whether **SELinux** is properly configured or not. If SELinux is not properly configured than apache won't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please setup the correct hostname for your server and check " journalctl -xn " command out while restarting httpd services on yoru server, You will get exact root cause of your httpd issues with journalctl -xn command.

Comment: Hello - Sure. Sorry for coming back late. This problem still persists. I'll give this a go soon.

Answer (score 2):

it was happened to me when i install/uninstall free-ipa, because of which nss.conf has been created inside /etc/httpd/conf.d/nss.conf, you can give a try by just moving this file to another directory as i did, now httpd service is working like a charm.